# why i need Xcode to install some software packages

Tags: xcode, macos

why i need Xcode to install some software packages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) is Apple's tool for developing iOS and Mac apps.

Your real question is why you need Xcode to install some software packages. The reason is that some software packages, usually open-source Unix packages, come with source code instead of a prebuilt binary file to install. They require you to compile the code in the package before installing it. When you buy a new Mac, it does not come with compilers. Xcode contains the compilers.

Apple provides a package of command-line tools to download so you can download the compilers without needing to install Xcode, which is a huge app. You can find the command-line tools package at Apple's [developer downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/download/). You need an Apple developer account to access the developer downloads, but you can create a free account.

Comment: okay thank you. I want to ask something else was my question stupid or what i don't know why i took downvotes :p

Comment: The most likely reason for the downvotes is that the first part of your question, what is Xcode, can be answered quickly with an Internet search. The first result when you search for Xcode in Google or DuckDuckGo is Apple's Xcode page, which I linked to in my answer.

Comment: okay thank you so much i'm going to edit it in order to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find what Xcode is on the Mac App Store.

Anyway, it is software made by Apple. It is used by developers to make `iOS`, `MacOS`, and other Apple platforms for making apps. To use it, you will need to be registered in the [Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/) through your Apple ID (cannot distribute) or through paying `£99/year`.

Hope this helps give you a brief idea. You shouldn't need to install Xcode if you are not a developer.