# Unable to finish Docker Install on Mac book Error invoking remote method 'desktop-go-backend'

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose

I'm trying to install Docker Desktop but get the following error at the final step of installation:

I have a Mackbook with the M1 chip and OS Ventura 13.2.1.

I have already tried to install with homebrew cask, but this did not work, so I switched to trying to download from the website: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/, and this is what is giving me the error. I'm able to download and run the installer. I am able to go all the way to the final step, where I choose between the Recommended Settings or Advanced Settings (set manually). When I choose either option and hit 'Submit' I get this error.

Note: I do not have Rosetta 2, and cannot install it on this device.

```
Error invoking remote method 'desktop-go-backend': 
Error: {"message":"<nil>: installing vmnetd: retrieving vmnetd version from
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.vmnetd.plist: reading plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.vmnetd.plist:
open /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.vmnetd.plist:
no such file or 
directory
\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.getValueFromPlist\n\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/vmnetd.go:175\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.setupVmnetd\n\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/vmnetd.go:85\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.ApplyCustomConfiguration\n\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/privileged.go:137\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.ConfigCmd.func1\n\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/privileged.go:59\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.
(*Command).execute\n\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:916\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.
(*Command).ExecuteC\n\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:1044\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.
(*Command).Execute\n\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:968\nmain.main\n\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/main.go:185\nruntime.main\n\truntime/proc.go:250\nruntime.goexit\n\truntime/asm_arm64.s:1172\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.setupVmnetd\n\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/vmnetd.go:87\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.ApplyCustomConfiguration\n\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/privileged.go:137\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.ConfigCmd.func1\n\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/privileged.go:59\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.
(*Command).execute\n\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:916\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC\n\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:1044\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.
(*Command).Execute\n\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:968\nmain.main\n\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/main.go:185\nruntime.main\n\truntime/proc.go:250\nruntime.goexit\n\truntime/asm_arm64.s:1172"}
```

Comment: How are you trying to install it? With homebrew or what?

Comment: @Lukas I have updated my post with some more details. I was trying to use the .dmg file on their website because brew installation did not work for me.

Comment: I'm having this problem after uninstalling the downloadable docker desktop, and reinstalling with 'brew'.

The docker uninstaller left a bunch of dead binaries on my computer, which I had to delete manually to get the brew command to finish. Once it finally did, I'm now left with this error.

Comment: @douliman I'm not sure if this will help you, but I had to also update XCode before running the cask install as mentioned below. I didn't include that in the answer as I wasn't sure it actually contributed to solving my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the fix!
So, I wasn't able to figure out the cause of this issue, but eventually tried fully uninstalling the 'Docker Desktop' from my Mac and then used the following command

```
brew install --cask docker
```

This reinstall worked for me. This didn't work the first time I tried above option, but it did eventually work as expected!

Comment: This worked for me after I upgraded to the latest xcode-select (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617930/7680360). Whole process was: uninstall old docker, upgraded xcode-select, install docker using brew command

Comment: @HenryMunro What is xcode-select and what does it have to do with docker?

Comment: @Gena xcode-select are the command line tools for XCode. It contains the compilers needed for downloading apps. You can learn a bit more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523573/why-i-need-xcode-to-install-some-software-packages

Comment: I guess you're not uninstalling from the Troubleshooting menu? Did you just delete the .app file?