# Docker Desktop install error on Mac book Pro - OS Monterey - Error: Error invoking remote method 'desktop-go-backend'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-daemon

I tried installing Docker Desktop using Docker Desktop for Mac (Intel Chip) and it failed with the following error:

```
Error invoking remote method 'desktop-go-backend': Error: {"message":"installing vmnetd: retrieving vmnetd version from /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.vmnetd.plist: reading plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.vmnetd.plist: open /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.vmnetd.plist: no such file or directory\\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.getValueFromPlist\\n\\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/vmnetd.go:175\\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.setupVmnetd\\n\\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/vmnetd.go:85\\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.ApplyCustomConfiguration\\n\\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/privileged.go:137\\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.ConfigCmd.func1\\n\\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/privileged.go:59\\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(\*Command).execute\\n\\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:940\\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(\*Command).ExecuteC\\n\\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:1068\\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(\*Command).Execute\\n\\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:992\\nmain.main\\n\\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/main.go:185\\nruntime.main\\n\\truntime/proc.go:250\\nruntime.goexit\\n\\truntime/asm_amd64.s:1598\\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.setupVmnetd\\n\\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/vmnetd.go:87\\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.ApplyCustomConfiguration\\n\\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/privileged.go:137\\ngithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged.ConfigCmd.func1\\n\\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/privileged/privileged.go:59\\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(\*Command).execute\\n\\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:940\\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(\*Command).ExecuteC\\n\\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:1068\\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(\*Command).Execute\\n\\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:992\\nmain.main\\n\\tgithub.com/docker/pinata/mac/tools/install/main.go:185\\nruntime.main\\n\\truntime/proc.go:250\\nruntime.goexit\\n\\truntime/asm_amd64.s:1598"}
```

I tried uninstalling and re-installing Docker desktop for mac few times. It did not solve the problem. Then I found this answer - [Unable to finish Docker Install on Mac book Error invoking remote method 'desktop-go-backend'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76201452/unable-to-finish-docker-install-on-mac-book-error-invoking-remote-method-deskto)

I tried the command - brew install --cask docker

It said the following error: there is already an App at '/Applications/Docker.app'.

I tried running command -

```
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/uninstall
```

and got zsh: no such file or directory: `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/uninstall`

I ran the commmand to check where is Docker installed

```
ls -ltrh /usr/local/bin/docker
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    54B Jun  1 14:01 /usr/local/bin/docker -\> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker
```

I ran the command

```
rm -rf /Applications/Docker.app
```

to remove the Docker app, then I checked docker again with command

```
ls -ltrh /usr/local/bin/docker
```

and got

```
ls -ltrh /usr/local/bin/docker
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    54B Jun  1 14:01 /usr/local/bin/docker -\> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker

Found all docker binaries (.venv) ➜  respell git:(master) ls -ltrh /usr/local/bin/docker\*
```

Ran the command  to remove all docker binaries

Then ran the command - brew install --cask docker - again

This time I got the following error:

```
Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/hub-tool'.
```

Again manually deleted the binary file

```
ls -ltrh /usr/local/bin/hub-tool
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    56B Jun  1 14:01 /usr/local/bin/hub-tool -\> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/hub-tool
(.venv) ➜  respell git:(master) rm -rf /usr/local/bin/hub-tool
```

Tried running the command `brew install --cask docker` again

This time got the error:

```
Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/kubectl.docker'.
```

Again manually deleted the binary file

Ran the command `brew install --cask docker` again

This time got the error:

```
Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/vpnkit'.
```

Again manually deleted the binary file

Ran the command brew `install --cask docker` again

This time got the error:

```
Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli'.
```

Again manually deleted the binary file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 30):

Official instructions didn't work for me. These commands worked.

```
$ brew uninstall --cask docker --force
$ brew uninstall --formula docker --force
$ brew install --cask docker
```

[Source](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/146078#issuecomment-1527357453)

Answer (score 11):

I had similar error:

`Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/docker-index'.`

And the only file related to docker was docker-index,

```bash
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/docker*
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  60 Dec  5 18:51 /usr/local/bin/docker-index -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-index
```

So I renamed it:

```bash
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/docker-index /usr/local/bin/docker-index-old
```

Then reinstall:
`brew reinstall --cask docker`

Installed successfully:

```bash
==> Installing Cask docker
==> Moving App 'Docker.app' to '/Applications/Docker.app'
==> Linking Binary 'docker' to '/usr/local/bin/docker'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-compose' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-compose' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose-v1'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-credential-desktop' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-desktop'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-credential-ecr-login' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-credential-osxkeychain' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-index' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-index'
==> Linking Binary 'hub-tool' to '/usr/local/bin/hub-tool'
==> Linking Binary 'kubectl' to '/usr/local/bin/kubectl.docker'
==> Linking Binary 'docker.bash-completion' to '/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/docker'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-compose.bash-completion' to '/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose'
==> Linking Binary 'docker.zsh-completion' to '/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_docker'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-compose.zsh-completion' to '/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_docker_compose'
==> Linking Binary 'docker.fish-completion' to '/opt/homebrew/share/fish/vendor_completions.d/docker.fish'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-compose.fish-completion' to '/opt/homebrew/share/fish/vendor_completions.d/docker-compose.fish'
==> Linking Binary 'com.docker.vpnkit' to '/usr/local/bin/vpnkit'
==> Linking Binary 'com.docker.cli' to '/usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli'
  docker was successfully installed!
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `brew uninstall docker` may very likely leave some files in the filesystem, which prevent `brew install docker --cask` to work. As others suggested, we'll need to remove these files manually. Fortunately there doesn't seem to be any side-effects.

This is what I did:

```
brew uninstall docker docker-compose
rm /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/docker
rm /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_docker
rm /usr/local/share/fish/vendor_completions.d/docker.fish

brew install docker --cask
```

Basically you keep running `brew install docker --cask` and delete every file displayed as `Error` in your console, for example:

```
Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/docker'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this error got resolved after manually deleting all the files mentioned above and then running the command again:

```
>brew install --cask docker
>==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew->cask/02e856177979b59c39bcad4617ecf9660efc6052/Casks/docker.rb
>Already downloaded: >/Users/imaxxs/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/0d69aa12bea0f03a9be6de7e0c8>965972a6e4c2fd83f74f7721cd1d8f755f50c--docker.rb
>==> Downloading https://desktop.docker.com/mac/main/amd64/109717/Docker.dmg
>Already downloaded: >/Users/imaxxs/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/8b8a9b014fdc9feea8b25312eb4>22310d409838134155da094b83563a337274c--Docker.dmg
>==> Installing Cask docker
>==> Moving App 'Docker.app' to '/Applications/Docker.app'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker' to '/usr/local/bin/docker'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker-compose' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker-compose' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose-v1'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker-credential-desktop' to '/usr/local/bin/docker->credential-desktop'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker-credential-ecr-login' to '/usr/local/bin/docker->credential-ecr-login'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker-credential-osxkeychain' to >'/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker-index' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-index'
>==> Linking Binary 'hub-tool' to '/usr/local/bin/hub-tool'
>==> Linking Binary 'kubectl' to '/usr/local/bin/kubectl.docker'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker.bash-completion' to >'/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/docker'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker-compose.bash-completion' to >'/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker.zsh-completion' to '/usr/local/share/zsh/site->functions/_docker'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker-compose.zsh-completion' to >'/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_docker_compose'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker.fish-completion' to >'/usr/local/share/fish/vendor_completions.d/docker.fish'
>==> Linking Binary 'docker-compose.fish-completion' to >'/usr/local/share/fish/vendor_completions.d/docker-compose.fish'
>==> Linking Binary 'com.docker.vpnkit' to '/usr/local/bin/vpnkit'
>==> Linking Binary 'com.docker.cli' to '/usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli'
>  docker was successfully installed!`enter code here`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I started to install docker and the installation failed due to connection issues so my brew was really messy with an unfinished installation. When I tried to install docker again with the same command `brew install --cask docker`, brew complained some files/folders already existed.
I would say it's pretty "safe" to delete these files/folders, brew will tell you what's causing the problem, **check the creation date just to be sure**, and delete anything related to docker while trying to install with the same command.

(In my opinion Mac uninstaller it's terrible, in a more extreme case, you can try installing some cleaner software, [e.g. "MacCleaner Pro", "Cleaner One"] to remove junk files and try to reinstall again)